# Pthreads’ manpages really don’t cover very much; where can I find more info?

Tags: pthreads, manpage

The `pthread_*` manpages are really, really sparse in lots of areas; for instance, for all I can tell, the various `pthread_attr_set*` are *completely* undocumented — that is, I can’t figure out what each of the various types of attributes **actually do**!

The only other useful sources of information I’ve found, than the manpages, are the famous [pthreads tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and [pthreads-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/conformance.html) documentation… neither of which helps in this particular case, and many others.

Where else can I go for information about *what* pthreads’ various functions *actually do*, short of digging into an open-source implementation (which is quite likely over my head)?

Comment: Which specifically are you uncertain about?  Some, such as [pthread_attr_setstacksize](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_attr_setstacksize.html) and [pthread_attr_setguardsize](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_attr_setguardsize.html) are more clear than others (e.g. [pthread_attr_setscope](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_attr_setscope.html))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the actual spec for POSIX threads would help?

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html

I've generally found that if I want to know how something works in POSIX-land, it's easiest to go straight to the spec.

Comment: I think I’ll find that very useful! I forget all of this is specified in detail; I’m used to resorting to manpages to learn things.

I’m actually working on OS X; would you happen to have an associated link to the relevant part of whatever other specs govern the non-POSIX-standardized parts (like `pthread_attr_setscope(3)`) handy?

Comment: @elliott, I linked [pthread_attr_setscope](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_attr_setscope.html) at Open Group above.  I believe it is part of the POSIX Threads Extension.

Answer (score 1):

I find https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ very helpful as well.